# Sudden DNS problem

Tags: networking, dns

Running 20.04. I have a networking problem that has just started today: I can't open new sites in Firefox.

This is my desktop on my home network. Other machines connected to the network, both wired and wireless, can open new sites, so it's not a problem with the router. Existing pages or sites that are already open also seem to be fine! I can open new tabs of YouTube, which I already had open, but not of Reddit, which I didn't.

I guess this is DNS? If I use nslookup on the unwired laptop, a Mac, I get this:

```
> news.bbc.co.uk
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
news.bbc.co.uk  canonical name = newswww.bbc.net.uk.
Name:   newswww.bbc.net.uk
Address: 212.58.249.144
Name:   newswww.bbc.net.uk
Address: 212.58.244.56
```

I get the same information, laid out slightly differently, from the wired Windows laptop. If I try this from the Ubuntu desktop, I get this:

```
> news.bbc.co.uk
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   news.bbc.co.uk
Address: 192.168.8.1
news.bbc.co.uk  canonical name = newswww.bbc.net.uk.
```

That looks to me like the name hasn't been resolved properly? I wanted to switch to using Google's DNS servers as a test, but I can't even reach them:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.8.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Unreachable

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Output from ip:

```
cjb@cjb-MS-7C02:~$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp34s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:d8:61:d0:da:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.19/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp34s0
       valid_lft 63472sec preferred_lft 63472sec
    inet6 2a01:110f:1333:8500:92e:2196:d2f2:8691/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 877sec preferred_lft 277sec
    inet6 2a01:110f:1333:8500:a293:a055:4054:b1a2/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 877sec preferred_lft 277sec
    inet6 fe80::a0e0:143c:e26:e29b/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enx001e101f0000: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1e:10:1f:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.8.100/24 brd 192.168.8.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx001e101f0000
       valid_lft 63468sec preferred_lft 63468sec
    inet6 fe80::f057:e421:11fb:9879/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I haven't used "ip" before, but I am surprised by 3) in that output. I only have one physical network interface in the machine, at least, that's all I remember. 2) has the IP address and MAC address that the router knows about.

```
cjb@cjb-MS-7C02:~$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Apr 22  2020 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

I guess this means that the file is effectively a fake, and networking is managed somewhere else?

Output from resolvectl as follows:

```
cjb@cjb-MS-7C02:~$ resolvectl status
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                

Link 3 (enx001e101f0000)
      Current Scopes: DNS        
DefaultRoute setting: yes        
       LLMNR setting: yes        
MulticastDNS setting: no         
  DNSOverTLS setting: no         
      DNSSEC setting: no         
    DNSSEC supported: no         
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.8.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.8.1
          DNS Domain: ~.         

Link 2 (enp34s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS                      
DefaultRoute setting: yes                      
       LLMNR setting: yes                      
MulticastDNS setting: no                       
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                       
      DNSSEC setting: no                       
    DNSSEC supported: no                       
  Current DNS Server: fe80::46ad:b1ff:febf:c052
         DNS Servers: fe80::46ad:b1ff:febf:c052
                      192.168.1.1              
          DNS Domain: ~.                       
                      home
```

Again, I'm not sure what link 3 is in this case.

Some other details:

- I have recently moved flat and unpacked this machine, but it has worked fine for several days.
- I had unplugged some devices from power and reconnected them this morning, including the network switch that the wired machines plug into. Doesn't seem to be a problem for other wired machines.
- Logging into the router, I can see that it has assigned 192.168.1.19 to the desktop. I can ping that IP from other machines in the network.
- The first uncommented line in /etc/resolv.conf is "nameserver 127.0.0.53", which seems wrong?

Am I right that this is a DNS problem? How do I find out exactly what is wrong, and put it right? What other information do I need?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and also: `ip addr show`

Comment: Also show `resolvectl status` output too because of the Ubuntu laptop using ResolveD, so we can see what DNS servers SystemD is pointing to for queries.

Comment: You might try disabling IPV6.  The rest look like a normal systemd-resolve setup.

Comment: If you can't even ping to any IP like 1.1.1.1 then it isn't a DNS problem. Login to the router and try to ping from it. Try also disabling firewall temporarily.

Comment: Have you attempted to set up your ethernet connection in Network Manager? Please check, reset all settings to Automatic and reboot. It appears that you ndeed have both an internal and a USB ethernet. To what network are other devices, phones, tablets, etc., on the same router connected? 192.168.8.xx or 192.168.1.xx?

Comment: `nameserver 127.0.0.53` in resolv.conf is NORMAL if you are on an Ubuntu that uses `systemd-resolved` to handle DNS - hence why I asked for the `resolvectl status` output.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was something else that I didn't mention. I have a USB 4G dongle, with no actual data allowance, that I use for picking up text messages from another SIM.

I forgot that I plugged it in this morning, because I don't think of it as an internet connection, but I guess it was recognised as one, and the routing table was re-written? I only remembered it because I thought I could try disconnecting the USB Bluetooth dongle to see it that improved things.

Anyway, I pulled it out of the hub, Ubuntu flashed a notification that I had removed something, and now everything works as it should.